# Can I use the parent of the root layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

Any View has a parent. If I check the main layout of an activity, I see it has a parent, too. It is a FrameLayout, that also has a parent - itself. Others activities' layouts are not its children, it has only one child - the main layout I have started from.

But if it is a FrameLayout, it could take other children, couldn't it? Can I use it somehow? Sometimes its use would make the tree of layouts one storey lower. Is it possible? How can I reach it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, absolutely - in fact, exactly what you propose is described in [this article](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html).

Comment: Oh, yes, I have read it, but somehow forgotten and had not connected it with the parent of the root layout that I see while inspecting it. It is even easy enough - no tricks needed. Thank you.